# Form APi Could not parse property path Unexpected token

Tags: forms

Using

- Drupal 9.1.4
- symfony/property-access I think is on 5.2.0 [that's the last version mentioned in the changelog]

I have a custom built form with some date and number fields, for example:

```
$form['calculator']['chargeable_consideration'] = [
  '#type' => 'number',
  '#min' => 0,
  '#step' => 0.01,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#size' => 13,
  '#attributes' => [
    'placeholder' => '£0.00',
  ],
  '#title' => $this->t('description text (£) <button class="tooltip-anchor" title="pop up text">?</button>'),
  '#prefix' => '<div class="form-group">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
];
```

I have validation checking the dates are within a range, but nothing to check the numbers.

if I use the numbers

- 10000.85
- 123456789.70
- 1234567890

the form works as expected.

If I use the numbers

- 100000.85
- 123456789.71

I get the following error

```
Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\InvalidPropertyPathException: Could not parse property path "calculator][chargeable_consideration". Unexpected token "[" at position 11. in Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyPath->__construct() (line 111 of vendor\symfony\property-access\PropertyPath.php).
Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor->getPropertyPath('calculator][chargeable_consideration') (Line: 120)
Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor->getValue(Array, 'calculator][chargeable_consideration') (Line: 406)
Drupal\custom_form\Form\CustomForm->validateForm(Array, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 82)
```

How do I prevent it from throwing this exception?

Answer (score -1):

'#title' should be a plain text. you have added html code Button in it.